# Using Kotlin's extension function to suppress a returned value

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

I am using `Kotlin` in a spring boot application. Especially in the services, I have found that some of the function need to suppress the returned value from repository. For example, here is a `save()` that saves an entity without returning the persisted entity id:

```
fun save(person: Person) {
    personRepository.save(person)
}
```

As you can see that this function simply delegates the call to the `JpaRepository#save(...)` and does not return anything. What I wanted to do was something like this:

```
fun save(person: Person) = personRepository.save(person)
```

In order to do this, I have created an extension function:

```
fun Any.ignoreReturn() = Unit
```

and then make the call to the `personRepository#save(...) as:

```
fun save(person: Person) = personRepository.save(person).ignoreReturn()
```

What I wanted to know was:

1. Is this the right way to do it?
2. Are there side  effects to such extension function as I am extending `Any`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to do it like this:

```
fun save(person: Person): Unit = let { personRepository.save(person) }
```

Important part there is to declare the function to return Unit so the generated code from `let` wont need to return what `personRepository.save(person)` is returning. You can test it, just remove `: Unit` part and you get different signature for your save function.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks

Comment: Why is that any better than the shorter, simpler, more standard `fun save(person: Person) { personRepository.save(person) }`?

Comment: No-one was asking which is better.